# How to get following output in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT A.Name AS ArlnName
    ,RD.RD_Slab
    ,IsNull(RD.RD_Publ_Rate, 0) AS RD_Publ_Rate
FROM RateHead RH
LEFT OUTER JOIN RateDetl RD ON RH.RH_LocCode = RD.RD_LocCode
    AND RH.RH_DocNo = RD.RD_DocNo
INNER JOIN AirlineMast A ON RH.RH_Airline = A.Code
INNER JOIN AirlineLocation AL ON RH.RH_LocCode = AL.LocCode
    AND RH.RH_Airline = AL.Code
    AND IsNull(AL.RatesAvailable, '') = 'Y'
LEFT OUTER JOIN CommodityMast CM ON CM.Code = RH.RH_SubCommodity
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND RH.RH_LocCode = 'BOM'
    AND IsNull(AL.RatesAvailable, '') = 'Y'
    AND RH.RH_DocNo IN (
        21038
        ,20708
        ,19886
        ,7876
        ,21146
        ,21009
        ,21121
        ,20921
        ,21195
        ,21210
        ,20925
        ,21182
        ,21143
        ,21191
        ,20857
        ,21082
        ,20481
        ,20533
        ,20314
        ,20387
        ,21173
        ,21198
        ,20635
        ,20657
        ,20099
        ,21192
        ,20928
        ,20590
        ,21066
        ,20862
        ,20985
        ,21128
        ,20897
        ,21211
        )
    AND RD.RD_Destn IN ('DXB')
ORDER BY RH.RH_WEF DESC
    ,RH.RH_DocNo DESC
```

> Somehow I got this output using the above Query.

```
   AirLineName         Slab(Value)  Public_Rate
------------------------------------------------
    Aeroflot Cargo      -45.00      263.00
    Aeroflot Cargo      45.00       219.00
    Aeroflot Cargo      100.00      184.00
    Aeroflot Cargo      300.00      176.00
    Aeroflot Cargo      500.00      150.00
    Aeroflot Cargo      1000.00     130.00

    Air Arabia Cargo    -45.00      140.00
    Air Arabia Cargo    45.00       130.00
    Air Arabia Cargo    100.00      95.00
    Air Arabia Cargo    250.00      85.00
    Air Arabia Cargo    500.00      70.00
```

After this, I want Output this like this. Here (if slab value is minus then it will come on Normal Column name(Public_Rate value) and if slab in plus then.
It will pick the value from Public_Rate it goes to different category like +20 +45 +100 +250 +300 +500 +1000 depends on Public_Rate column value... )

```
AirLineName         Normal    +20   +45   +100    +250   +300   +500  +1000   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aeroflot Cargo      263.00          219    184            176    150   130

Air Arabia Cargo    140             130     95      85            70
```

I don't have any idea or Logic how to write this query....Thank you!!

Comment: What are the underlying input?

Comment: @@Suraj Kumar Input based on UI that part i will manage.....but I want only How can i achieve the following outpt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this below logic considering your output as input data-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ecedb94eb4d3f84f4a9bf745f1c5c67e)

```
SELECT AirLineName,
SUM(CASE WHEN Slab_Value = -45 THEN Public_Rate ELSE 0 END) 'Normal',
SUM(CASE WHEN Slab_Value>= 20 AND Slab_Value < 45 THEN Public_Rate ELSE 0 END) '+20',
SUM(CASE WHEN Slab_Value>= 45 AND Slab_Value < 100 THEN Public_Rate ELSE 0 END) '+45',
SUM(CASE WHEN Slab_Value>= 100 AND Slab_Value < 250 THEN Public_Rate ELSE 0 END) '+100',
SUM(CASE WHEN Slab_Value>= 250 AND Slab_Value < 300 THEN Public_Rate ELSE 0 END) '+250',
SUM(CASE WHEN Slab_Value>= 300 AND Slab_Value < 1000 THEN Public_Rate ELSE 0 END) '+300',
SUM(CASE WHEN Slab_Value>= 1000 THEN Public_Rate ELSE 0 END) '+1000'
FROM your_output
GROUP BY AirLineName
```